# Forwarding every message in a folder to a specified email address

Tags: email

How can I forward each message in a mail folder (I am using alpine where each mail folder is actually a single file in mbox format) to a specified recipient? I would like each message in the folder to go out as a separate forwarded message.

Answers on how to do this with different software would also be welcome.

Comment: it may help to list the `MTA` you are using as there are about 20 different kinds

Comment: I am using Exim 4.72

Answer (score 2):

open the file using mutt

```
mutt -f FILENAME
```

tag all

```
T$ [enter]
```

forward ("bounce") tagged

```
;b
```

enter the email address etc.

finally

```
q
```

to exit

Comment: They specifically asked for Alpine.

Comment: @Sparhawk I think using `mutt` is a fine answer because alpine probably cannot do it. The important part is that the mailbox is in mbox format.

Comment: Okay, I don't know enough about alpine, but the answer should state that it's impossible then.

Comment: I am not particular about using alpine. I mentioned that just because I wasn't sure what the mailbox format was. I would be even happier if there was a command-line solution.

Comment: @sparhawk  he specifically said he's _using_ alpine, He didn'r state that it was the only tool available, I'm not familiar enough with alpine to say if it can do this or not. This task is easily performed using mutt, if he doesn't have mutt and can't install it (or have admin install it) or if he doesn't have shell access, then yeah, mutt is not a solution.

Comment: @AmritanshuPrasad , without clarification in the question, then does that mean answers based on Thunderbird, Wine/Outlook, etc. are acceptable?

Comment: Certainly; maybe my mistake was to tag it "alpine". I think such answers may be useful to other users who come across this issue.